# Xamarin iOS only crash physical iPhone when you open an app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm facing a strange error. App only crashes on **physical** device. But iOS simulator does not. It working fine.

The strange thing is it crashes when you open an app and `FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)` method does not call at all.

What possibilities might have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the third-party iOS library (nuget package) was configured to iOS-Simulator. not physical iOS.

After the package author released hot-fix, it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the linker Behaviour  use the SDK-Only
go to Xamarin.iOS solution select ios build choose linker behaviour and change it

Comment: I tried SDK-Only and No Link.It did not work.

Comment: Paste the crash error here.please

Comment: Hi @Thaer Mosa, It seems package issue. I will contact them.

OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.5 (19F77)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.61.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: